# generate URL within ZF2 actions

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What is the best way to generate URLs within inside Zendframework 2 Controller/Action ?

Available Route : 'application'

Controller : 'Customer'

Action : 'Update'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
public function someAction()
{
    //use url plugin in controller
    $link = $this->url()->fromRoute('application', array('controller'=>'customer','action'=>'update'));
}
```